# Like button no longer works

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-like

The like button for my facebook app page stopped working a few days ago. I have added SSL support to my app, but this hasn't solved the problem. I still see the number of likes, but other users just see 0 and when they click the count increments to 1 for a second and then flashes back to 0. I really need help with this. I've tried every solution I can find online and nothing solves it.

Here is the URL of my facebook app: http://apps.facebook.com/speeksy

If you go to the page for creating a Like button for this url, you will see the problem.

Thanks,
Barry

Answer (score 1):

This problem is fixed. I found the problem by going to the 'Like' button generation page and typing in my URL. Then it gave me a link to the Admin page for the like button. On the admin page I saw that the admin page was scheduled for deletion. Not sure why this was, but maybe I did this because I was making sure the admin page wasn't being confused with the App Profile page. Anyway, canceling the scheduled deletion made it work again.